# How to make the app wait until something (until variable changes) happens

Tags: java, android

I created a main class and an adapter for my ListView. In this adapter I created three different types of rows. One of them is a row with EditText. In the adapter class I created a Listener for "Enter" click. After an user clicks "Enter" button, the information entered in EditText saves in a variable.

What I need: I want my app (my main class) wait until this variable changes (from null to something) and after continue doing some actions. 
I tried to create a loop, but if ended up with error.

Comment: you mean you want to call something like a function once a variable changed ?

Comment: Post the loop you tried and the error you got.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Read this so your things don't get downvoted to oblivion lol:   http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use onEditorDoneListener on the edittext(example is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At0iJB3Sb24)) when the user presses done button on the keyboard, you can verify the value of the editText and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> After an user clicks "Enter" button, the information entered in EditText saves in a variable.

It seems that this variable (presumably a String) is only ever changed when the "Enter" button is pressed. So whatever action you want when that String is changed, put them into the onClick method in your Java:

```
private void enterButtonOnClick(View v) {
      // Store the text from EditText into the String variable  here    
      // ...   


      // Your string variable just changed, so do the desired action...
      // Stuff 
      //       and 
      //            things
}
```

And then in your XML, add this in the button attribute :

```
android:onClick="enterButtonOnClick"
```